# Android studio, configure gradle project takes forever

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After changing the gradle build file to use gradle build tool 0.8.+,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
```

my Android studio is stuck forever at "refreshing X Gradle project". I tried to restart AS, didn't work. I did even change gradle build tool back to 0.7.+, even downgrade my AS from 0.4.4 back to 0.4.2, still no hopes. Anyone experienced this before? pls help
Tks.

**Update**: now I tried deleting all old .iml files and .idea folder, and reimported, now it's stuck at "Building X Gradle project info", seems like forever.

Building from commandline is perfectly fine.

**Update 2:** Log file included as requested (.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log\idea.log)

```
2014-02-17 00:45:27,412 [  46868]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Failed to update Maven indices for: [http://download.crashlytics.com/maven] http://download.crashlytics.com/maven 
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerIndexerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.updateIndex(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at $Proxy99.updateIndex(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:106)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:167)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:102)
    at $Proxy99.updateIndex(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$3.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.updateIndex(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateContext(MavenIndex.java:317)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateOrRepair(MavenIndex.java:276)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.updateOrRepair(MavenIndices.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.doUpdateIndices(MavenIndicesManager.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.access$200(MavenIndicesManager.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$3.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:231)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl$2.run(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:193)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:314)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.updateIndex(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.retrieve(Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.java:108)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.AbstractResourceFetcher.retrieve(AbstractResourceFetcher.java:22)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.downloadIndexProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:484)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$100(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:65)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$IndexAdaptor.setProperties(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:771)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:945)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl$2.run(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:190)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to locate resource in repository
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.retrieve(Maven3ServerIndexFetcher.java:100)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1664)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1662)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1660)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1243)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:122)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1613)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
    ... 28 more
2014-02-17 00:45:56,749 [  76205]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-02-17 00:45:56,750 [  76206]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2014-02-17 00:45:56,756 [  76212]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 25 project components initialized in 20 ms 
2014-02-17 00:45:56,757 [  76213]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2014-02-17 00:47:30,887 [ 170343]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$000(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:153)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1017)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.tryLock(LockStateAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.tryLockState(LockFileAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lockStateRegion(DefaultFileLockManager.java:317)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:260)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:132)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:87)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:74)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getIdle(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:149)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(ActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2014-02-17 00:47:30,893 [ 170349]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'C:/Users/Tung/TripGoify/TripGoify' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:170)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$000(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at
```

Comment: Have you tried reimporting the project? Just delete all .iml files and the .idea folder and reimport it. And also, building from the command line gives you any error?

Comment: i think that is not the issue in this case rciovati.

Comment: @rciovati building from commandline is fine. Still trying re-importing, AS already takes some time doing so now.

Comment: I'm getting this with gradle build tools v0.11, but not with 0.10 / android.buildToolsVersion 19.0.1. None of the suggested solutions work. I believe this is related to CrashLytics. Log says `File: http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties , ReasonPhrase:Not Found.`

Comment: I've been experiencing a problem similar to yours and opened this bug in IDEA: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127247

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This could be anything, but in my case, it is due to an invalid HTTP proxy and some libraries can't be downloaded. In Settings-> HTTP Proxy, set to "None".

Comment: this is the default configuration after installing Android Studio

Comment: Yes, I suggest others to view @pyus13 answer below

Comment: In my case, I was using an HTTP proxy on my machine. Killing that (Charles.app) caused Android Studio to finish building my project immediately.

Comment: I had Charles running too. Closing Charles fixed it for me.

Comment: Also check your Internet connection

Comment: Now it is : Settings-> Appearence&Behaviour--> SystemSettings-->HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 19):

If you are on Windows check

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

whether the `gradle 1.10-all` is installed there or not inside the directory.

Android Studio downloads the whole distribution first time which is around 60 MB so it takes some time.

Check the distributionUrl in gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties and match the same in your dist directory if it is not available studio will download it. Distribution url will look like :

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

change it to whatever already installed will solve the problem.

**Note :** The directory name in dist and Zip name must same. Directory will be created while trying to download check whether the Zip is installed properly or not.

Comment: tks, my current settings are like what you suggested. Anything else to check?

Comment: Can you include the idea.log file ?

Comment: In Linux is the same, use this folder name: ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists

Comment: where is `distributionUrl in gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` on Windows ?

Comment: Inside your project root directory /gradle

Comment: I don't have wrapper folder in .gradle folder at all and I am experiencing stuck at the gradle. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: android tries to dowload the gradle files and could not download which is why it stops at that window. You can manually download the files and place it in that directory. Download from this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions ..download appropriate version and try reopening the android studio again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it

- deleting gradle and intellij files

  ```
  rm -rf .idea/ *.iml .gradle/
  ```
- reimporting the project on intellij
- choosing same jdk for gradle that you use on gradle terminal(makes sense if you use daemon)
  [image]
- and upgrading from gradle **2.4** to **2.13**

Comment: Only  this solution helped me.

Comment: @sunnyday I am happy for you

Comment: deleting whole folder named `.gradle` helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

delete gradle folder in your project folder then reopen it using studio, in choose dialog choose cancel, don't use grade wrapper to download latest version of gradle

Answer (score 3):

### If anyone face this sync stuck problem in mac, give this a try.

right click your

> android studio.app -> show package -> content -> gradle

and see the `gradle` version. In that folder,  now got to your android studio IDE and open your preference and go to

> Build, execution -> build tool - > gradle

check the preference there.   verify the path of gradle is as content - > ....   and last there will be gradle version, see if that matched the gradle version in the content of androidStudio.app

guess this helps someone.

Comment: helped me thanks, after updating Android Studio and faced with interminable gradle sync.

Answer (score 2):

after long research I finally found the proper solution, just add "ndkVersion 'yourNDKversion'" inside android section in your app level build.gradle and this solves every time

Comment: I encountered this problem after uninstalling my current NDK version and installing a new one. Reinstalling the previous NDK solved the problem, then I just needed to change the NDK version with the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was Genymotion plugin.
 Once i removed it from studio and restarted. It worked fine. 
I still don't know how that could happen as i regularly use genymotion with studio in my other machines. 
You can still run genymotion even if you remove studio plugin by starting emulator from genymotion itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have centos 7 64 bits installed on a virtualbox 5.0.16 virtual machine and gradle version 2.10 with Android Studio 2.0

The log file of gradle is located at `$HOME/.gradle/daemon/2.10` Log file: `daemon-<some number>.out.log`

By inspecting this log file I found out that `libz.so.1` was not found by `aapt`.

Despite that command "locate libz.so.1" output was

```
/usr/lib64/libz.so
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
```

`aapt` was not able to find it.

In order to solve the issue I had to execute

```
yum install zlib.i686
```

Once installed, Gradle started compiling. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in this regard was , replacing the **GRDADLE** *jar* and *properties* file from the respective project that you may be trying to import .

1. Build a project fresh or , copy the gradle jar and properties file from the working project
2. Now , further copy these files and replace with the "**Originaly**" not working gradle files of the project you are trying to import or the project where gradle build hangs

Bit late , but can be of some help to the future queries .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a multi-project setup and included two separate projects in `settings.gradle` featuring some overlapping properties. I'm not sure which *exact* properties caused this, but they were most likely name-related. Basically, instead of throwing an exception (*"duplicated [something] detected"*), Gradle went into an endless loop. Replacing the duplicated properties helped.

Answer (score 0):

change jdk path to the official ones not that you've downloaded with android studio then start a new project .

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me also (Aug/22 Gradle Version 7.3), after getting a "File write failed C:..." dialog the build stuck at "Configure projects..." forever. I tried everything on this post and some other things that I already knew but none of them work. The only solution I found was cloning the repository and start all over again.

Answer (score -1):

If you're opening a new GitHub project, all you need is a fast internet.