# Can't make a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 2.1.2.0v and when I want to make a project, have a problem.

[image]

Every thing about JDK is right.

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the android studio or gradle logs? Can you use gradle from the command line? It looks like it creates your project just fine,  but can't download the latest version of gradle.

Comment: Disconnect the internet and run the android studio. Try it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837465/android-studio-stuck-on-gradle-resolve-dependancies-debugcompile-or-detac

Answer (score 2):

Might due to proxy gradle couldn't download it's latest build files, there must be some connection issue you can alternatively do is get sdk from somewhere and in offline mode at least open one project, after it you can update all things and if problem occurs you can easily find solution as android studio clearly shows what are the problems behind these kinda of problems.

It can also happen due to antivirus sometimes,

Recommended reading : https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb#.8h6wyo50c

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171878/5476209

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815505/5476209

Comment: Working with offline gradle has a benefit, but you couldn't get the latest gradle build. So it will raise an issue once the project will use the online gradle build or any of module requires higher version of gradle dependency.... You can work with offline gradle build , to reduce the network usage and faster build, but **you have to make sure that you are updating your gradle version regularly!**