# Gradle sync stuck forever

Tags: file, gradle, synchronization

Im trying to build a project from multiple source folders but the gradle sync task gets stuck (0% forever)

```
task syncSharedCode(type: Sync) {
    group 'build auxiliary'
    from '../../base'
    into 'combined'
}

task build(type: Copy, dependsOn: ['syncSharedCode']) {
    group 'build'
    into 'combined'
    from 'custom'
    exclude "/shared/**/*_abstract.*"
}
```

There is no output after the sync task starts except acquiring and releasing a registry lock

```
11:19:35.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:19:35.691 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
11:19:35.691 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

I have no idea why it is stuck every time and I hope that you can give some insight.

Comment: What is your Gradle version? It can get stuck because of several different reasons. Take a look at links [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781569/android-studio-configure-gradle-project-takes-forever) and [two](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220611&thanks=220611&ts=1471888230).

Answer (score 0):

For me help to delete next folder with Active Build Variant here (or all folders):

> C:\Users\"user"\"your project folder"\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file

But I stack with this problem after check password in process of building signed APK